# Same user, Different cookies in Coldfusion Log

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

In my application the value for cookie for one user is getting overridden by another user's cookie value.
For example, User A logs in, when I print the cookie value in log it gives me User A cookie value.
But, once User B logs in I am getting same values for both the user A & B in the log.
Interesting thing is there are some token values which I am extracting from cookie and storing it in client variable. The client contains correct value for the respective users.

Tried writing the cookie values to the application log to verify.

```
writeLog(text="DEBUG: User Cokkie Details - { COOKIE : " & cookie.toString() & "}", application=true);
```

It looks pretty straight forward, but could I be writing it wrong?
Not an expert regarding the subject of matter, any help/suggestion is appreciated.

FYI : I recently started observing this issue, but no code change has been done in quite a time. Application uses CF2018 version.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any code. Are you rewriting cookie values anywhere in your code? Also, if you are storing to client variables and your cfengine client storage is set to "cookies" and you are also writing data manually to cookies, you might need to check if the cookie names are not conflicting. As I said, hard to tell without seeing any code.